# How to access objects created using one class from a different class in Python

Tags: python, class, object, multiple-instances

I have a problem related to accessing objects created using one class from an another class

In order simplify the problem 
lets say ,

I Have a Python Files called Box1.py , cart1.py and soldApples.py

```
 class Box1:
    def__init__(self):
      self.appleList = []

    def set_Apples(self,number1):
      self.appleList.append(number1):

    def get_Apples(self):
        return appleList
```

And the Main Class Called Cart1.py

```
  from Box1 import Box1
  NewSet = Box1()

  class cart1:
     def calculation()
        numberofApples = 5
        NewSet.set_Apples(numberofApples)

      return 0
```

Now I want to Access Object `"NewSet"` using another class

let's say soldApples.py

so How do I access to `"NewSet"` Object Created by Cart1.py using soldApples.py?

Thank you very much in advance guys.

Comment: `import Cart1` `Cart1.NewSet`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of your soldApples.py file write the line:

```
import Cart1
```

and then in your file you can refer to the `NewSet` variable as:

```
Cart1.NewSet
```

Alternatively if you just want that variable you can do:

```
from Cart1 import NewSet
```

and then your variable will be called

```
NewSet
```

Also you will want the files to be in the same folder.

Comment: Hi Menyah  Thank you very much for the quick response. made my day